# White flash with electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm developing a Javascript videogame with some friends, using **[Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)**.

We have a render problem, when we launch the game, some white blocks appears on the screen and we just have no clue of the source of this problem. You can see it on this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUepfTBhmH4

Can someone help us?

Comment: Are you using canvas? If not, check repaints.

Comment: If this is  a code-related question we will need to see some code to help. If not, it's off topic and doesn't belong here.

Comment: check line 37 of your code

Comment: You have your code & full app in front of you, we just have have a short clip on Youtube, who can be more helpful? Also do the blocks appear only after user makes those menu options appear?

Comment: @lei Honestly there's enough evidence in the video to probably determine the underlying issue. And i think OP understands that this might be something outside his application's code. And therefore posting code wouldn't be much help.

Answer (score 1):

In your video, [on this frame](http://puu.sh/rozTe/e05b335dee.jpg), it seems to me like it could be an issue with electrons rendering system. If your game objects are rendered as DOM elements you should look [simplifying your scene](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas?hl=en) or rendering to a canvas instead.

Comment: I'm working with Estiocle on this issue. We are thinking quite the same as you. We tried to remove as much code as we could (there was no Javascript anymore, only HTML and CSS) and the glitch is still there (less frequently but still there).

We developed the game initially on NW.js and everything worked. But when we switches to Electron, these gliches appear.

Any ideas to dig into ?

Comment: @ack other than the repaint stuff, which is sort of out of your hands (maybe send them an email / bug report and wait), you could try lowering the framerate to 30. Framerates around 30 are still fine in terms of playability imo. I'm not 100% sure that will help though.